# Read closely, or you will fail

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

> Jason's mother had 4 children. Three of their names were Penny, Nickel, and Dime. 
> What was the fourth child's name?

If you need a hint, you are very lucky for one:

> Read closely, or the answer is nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Answer

> Jason

Explanation

> Jason is his mother's child

Comment: You are... **correct.** Pretty much everybody I told this to could not get it, so I am slightly surprised. Good job!